# How to remove string after .com and "https://" from an URL in Python

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I need to merge two dataframe by using url as a primary key. However, there are some extra strings in the url like in df1, I have https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us.html, where in df2, I have https://www.mcdonalds.com

I need to remove the /us/en-us.html after the .com and the https:// from the url, so I can perform the merge using url between 2 dfs. Below is a simplified example. What would be the solution for this?

```
df1={'url': ['https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us.html','https://www.cemexusa.com/find-your- 
location']}
df2={'url':['https://www.mcdonalds.com','www.cemexusa.com']}

df1['url']==df2['url']
Out[7]: False
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) as suggested by others, or you could also use [`urlsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit). However, both will not handle `www.cemexusa.com`. So if you do not need the scheme in your key, you could use something like this:

```py
def to_key(url):
    if "://" not in url:  # or: not re.match("(?:http|ftp|https)://"", url)
        url = f"https://{url}"
    return urlsplit(url).hostname

df1["Key"] = df1["URL"].apply(to_key)
```

---

Here is a full working example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

from urllib.parse import urlsplit

df1_data = io.StringIO("""
URL,Description
https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us.html,Junk Food
https://www.cemexusa.com/find-your-location,Cemex
""")

df2_data = io.StringIO("""
URL,Last Update
https://www.mcdonalds.com,2021
www.cemexusa.com,2020
""")

df1 = pd.read_csv(df1_data)
df2 = pd.read_csv(df2_data)

def to_key(url):
    if "://" not in url:  # or: not re.match("(?:http|ftp|https)://"", url)
        url = f"https://{url}"
    return urlsplit(url).hostname
    
df1["Key"] = df1["URL"].apply(to_key)
df2["Key"] = df2["URL"].apply(to_key)

joined = df1.merge(df2, on="Key", suffixes=("_df1", "_df2"))

# and if you want to get rid of the original urls
joined = joined.drop(["URL_df1", "URL_df2"], axis=1)
```

The output of `print(joined)` would be:

```py
  Description                Key  Last Update
0   Junk Food  www.mcdonalds.com         2021
1       Cemex   www.cemexusa.com         2020
```

---

There may be other special cases not handled in this answer. Depending on your data, you may also need to handle an omitted `www`:

```py
urlsplit("https://realpython.com/pandas-merge-join-and-concat").hostname
# realpython.com

urlsplit("https://www.realpython.com").hostname  # also a valid URL
# www.realpython.com
```

---

What is the difference between `urlparse` and `urlsplit`?

It depends on your use case and what information you would like to extract. Since you do not need the URL's `params`, I would suggest using `urlsplit`.

> [`urlsplit()`] is similar to `urlparse()`, but does not split the `params` from the URL.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit

Comment: Thanks Thomas for sharing the full working example along with the solution to specials cases. Really appreciated it.

Comment: You are welcome. I also just added a section about the difference between `urlparse` and `urlsplit`.

Comment: This is awesome! I also realized in my full dataset, I noted some url don't even have www. in front of it, I guess I will add another condition within the if statement, by saying if 'www' and 'http://' not in url, then url = f"https://www.{url}"

Answer (score 2):

URLs are not trivial to parse. Take a look at the [urllib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) in the standard library.

Here's how you could remove the path after the domain:

```py
import urllib.parse

def remove_path(url):
    parsed = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
    parsed = parsed._replace(path='')
    return urllib.parse.urlunparse(parsed)

df1['url'] = df1['url'].apply(remove_path)
```

Comment: Thanks Angus, when I run the code, I have the same error as above which is AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'. Can you share some of your insights on this? Thanks

Comment: In your question you mentioned Pandas so I assumed that `df1` was a Pandas DataFrame. If you want to keep it as a dict of lists, you can do `df1['url'] = list(map(remove_path, df1['url']))`

Comment: Or, if you prefer, `df1['url'] = [remove_path(url) for url in df1['url']]`

Comment: oh yes you are right. In my real example, they are df and your codes work well!

Comment: but another problem is after I applied this, the 'www.cemexusa.com' in df2 is being removed entirely...

Comment: That's because it is missing `https://`. In that case you'll just want to compare the `hostname` for both dataframes, as described by @Thomas.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) and isolate the hostname:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

urlparse('https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us.html').hostname
# 'www.mcdonalds.com'
```

Comment: Thanks, when I run the below code, it throws me an error, can you give me more advice? 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: never mind, it's because df1 is not a really df. If I convert it to a DataFrame, it works! Thanks.

Comment: I encountered an issue which is after I applied this, the 'www.cemexusa.com' is being removed entirely from df2...